# PHP : How to post form data via another file?

Tags: php, forms, post, submit, form-submit

I have 2 files : index.php, form.php.

**form.php:**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "OK";
    // do something with post data

}

?>
    <form method="post" name="myform">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
    </form>
```

I call form.php by typing in browser address bar: `**`mysite/index.php?act=form`**`

In index.php I have these line:

```
    <?php

    switch($_REQUEST['act']){
        case "form":
            include("form.php"); break;

    }
...
```

But I had nothing (in form.php) when the form was submitted. All that I want is get posted data in form.php, not in index.php.

What was I wrong here?

Thansk for your time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change your line in form.php

```
<form method="post" name="myform" action="form.php">
```

or

```
<form method="post" name="myform" action="index.php?act=form">
```

Comment: @quangtruong1985, glad to help you. If this solution helped you please mark this as a accepted solution so that others will know that the problem has been solved.

Comment: You got it. I have to wait for 5 minutes to mark your answer as accepted (just dont know why I have to).

Comment: @Sabin +1 fore being 1 sec ahead of xdazz ;)

Answer (score 2):

So you need add the action attribute of the form:

```
<form action="/index.php?act=form" method="post" name="myform">
```